# How to format the output of cout using float values?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I found one ways to show my float value like decimal, but when I use in my code, didn´t show as I want it.

```
int p = 3.1415926536;
cout << setprecision(3) << p <<"\t";
```

I´m using c++ in visual studio 2010.

I need to know this because when I multiply a matrix it shows wrong values, but debbugin I see there is no error in my code.

The output shows a strange value.

Comment: Post the output please.

Comment: What you have will print "3", always.

Comment: `1.#J    5.15e+025       5.15e+025       1.#J`

There are 4 values like a matrix

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
int p = 3.1315926536
```

should be

```
double p = 3.1415926536;
```

Comment: double p = 3.1315926536; should be double p = 3.1415926536;